# why getting DebugBreak() on deleting an object

Tags: c++, mfc, debugbreak

I have an MFC dialog, which is called `Dlg1`

```
myobject* Dlg1 = new myobject();
```

This dialog has a parent dialog called A;  I have a function in  A, which is called on closing:

```
A::Destroy()
{
     if(Dlg1 )
           delete  Dlg1; // this is triggering `DebugBreak(); here i get A.exe has triggered a breakpoint, 
     // the rest of the code 
}
```

If I close `Dlg1` dialog, manually by clicking on the close button, then close the main dialog `A`, then everything is fine no problem. However, if `Dlg1` is running and I close A, then I get `DebugBreak()`. This issue occurs only in debug mode, in the release mode no problem.

Comment: _'Does anyone know what triggers this?'_ Deleting an already deleted pointer for instance ...

Comment: The debug heap detected heap corruption.  Nice feature.  Finding the cause is of course never simple.

Comment: There is no need to check for NULL when issuing a call to `delete`. So that check for `if(Dlg1 )` doesn't help you at all, unless you're calling Destroy() on the same object multiple times in succession.

Comment: It might help putting a `Dlg1 = nullptr;` after the `delete` statement (thus `if(Dlg1 )` makes sense).

Comment: @Samer _'I do this '_ So, why don't you show it in your sample? Did you think it's irrelevant?

Comment: @Samer - Is this code correct `myobject* Dlg1 = new myobject();`? If so, then that `Dlg1` is a local variable, different than the `Dlg1` you have in your `Destroy` method, or it is (heaven forbid) a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are to assume that the code you posted in your question is the actual code you're using, the issue may be this:

```
myobject* Dlg1 = new myobject();
```

Note that `Dlg1` is a local variable, not a member variable.  Then you have this:

```
A::Destroy()
{
  if (Dlg1 )
     delete  Dlg1; 
}
```

The `Dlg1` in the code above is the member variable `Dlg1` of class or struct `A`.  It more than likely was never initialized, due to your code creating a dynamic object locally by mistake.  Issuing a `delete` on an uninitialized pointer will wreak havoc.

If this is the issue, then to fix it, one suggestion is to have somewhere:

```
A::SomeFuntion()
{
    //...
    Dlg1 = new myobject();  // set the member variable Dlg1, not a local variable.
    //...,
}
```

where `SomeFunction` would be another member function of `A`.

Comment: Paul, Dlg1 is a member of A.

Comment: I am sure 'Dlg1' is not deleted explicitly, However, Before A is closed or Destroyed, I called `Dlg1->Onclose()` which calls `Dlg1->OnDestroy()`, so if the last call already deleted Dlg1 then yes, this is double delete then.